# How to get flutter windows desktop users screen width at runtime

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

So, normally I can get screen size by using `MediaQuery.of(context).size`, however I don't have access to context at runtime. Is there any package or API I can tap into to accomplish this ?

**EDIT:** Accepted @smorgan answer. Adding the pubspec.yaml entry with small use case for others, so they don't have to go digging.

**Noting this will eventually be removed and added into flutter core functionality (hopefully).

Also the `ref` field is the commit hash of current branch as of 12/15/21

**pubspec.yaml entry:**

```
window_size:
git:
  url: git://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
  path: plugins/window_size
  ref: 03d957e8b5c99fc83cd4a781031b154ab3de8753
```

**Getting Screen Size**

```
var screenSize = await getCurrentScreen();
print(screenSize?.frame.size);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`window_size`](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/window_size) plugin will let you get the current screen size, or a list of all screens and their sizes.

Comment: Thanks. Probably a broad question but, is there a timeframe when you think it may be in the flutter api? Trying to gauge when this may break.

Comment: Tested and working. Marking as correct answer. No other library is working for me.

Comment: Why would it break? Adding window support to the framework wouldn't have any effect on method channels.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for my flutter windows app:

https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_window

Comment: Its returning my applications window size, not the users screen size.

Comment: Well just maximize the screen using the plugin and then measure the size

Comment: Yea there must be some kind of bug, sometimes it comes back as size 0 and sometimes it comes back as 1280X720, which my current screen resolution is 1920X1080. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Weird, I guess desktop apps still have some hiccups to be worked out